# highcharts have data Labels only on some points

Tags: highcharts

I'm using `highcharts` to display machine logging data. Data is formatted/created through PHP. There's a switch on the page to let the user chose to have the X-axis show the time the values occurred, or just a counter.

For one series, the value is mostly zero but sometimes not. I would like to show a label when the value is not zero and only in this series.
for the `x-axis != time` option I'm using this:

```
[0,0,0,{y:125.71,dataLabels: {enabled: true}},0,0]
```

Turning the label on per point, that works.

When I switch to showing the time on X axis, I need to format the data like this:

```
[Date.UTC(2016, 6, 1, 09, 06), 0],[Date.UTC(2016, 6, 1, 09, 06), 0, [Date.UTC(2016, 6, 1, 09, 06), 216],[Date.UTC(2016, 6, 1, 09, 06), 0],[Date.UTC(2016, 6, 1, 09, 06), 0],[Date.UTC(2016, 6, 1, 09, 06), 0]
```

And I can't figure out how to show the label here. Is it possible in this data formatting too?

Also if there's any other way to do this :

```
if (value>0) {show label}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's essentially the same thing - you're either sending the data point as a single `y` value, an array of `x,y` values, or an object of `key: value` pairs, and you can mix and match like you did in the first example.

So this data array, which sends each data point as an array of x,y values, just needs one of the arrays sent as an object instead. This:

```
[
  [Date.UTC(2016, 6, 1, 09, 06), 0],
  [Date.UTC(2016, 6, 1, 09, 06), 216],
  [Date.UTC(2016, 6, 1, 09, 06), 0]
]
```

Becomes:

```
[
  [Date.UTC(2016, 6, 1, 09, 06), 0],
  {x: Date.UTC(2016, 6, 1, 09, 06), y: 216, dataLabels: { enabled: true }},
  [Date.UTC(2016, 6, 1, 09, 06), 0]
]
```

Just like you did with the non-datetime version.

The only difference is that you specify `'x':` as well as `'y':`

[[**EDIT**

As for the second part of your question, you can use the formatter to accomplish this as well:

```
dataLabels: {
  formatter: function() {
    return this.y > 0 ? this.y : '';
  }
}
```